# .NET Console.Readline doesn't read the first line entered

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a console application but the first input line is always ignored.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        try
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("I wrote: " + input);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

When I run this, the result is as follows:

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening? I already tried writing a line before the first line, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: obviously it's because you are calling `Console.ReadLine()` twice ... in fact you will only get every even input

Comment: If you used `line` instead of `string input = Console.ReadLine().ToString();` inside your loop, this would probably work as you expect.

Comment: @Selvin  you're right. Dumb mistake, totally overlooked this.

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I writed: " + line);
            string input = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("I writed: " + input);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

You were printing only `input` and never `line`

---

Maybe you wanted to do it this way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string input;
        while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I writed: " + input);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```